# unable to paste with xclip outside of terminal

Tags: xclip

I am trying to copy from the terminal with xclip and paste it into the unity desktop environment into gedit text editor. I can copy and paste with xclip in terminal:

```
$ cat line-size.c | xclip
xclip -o > input5.txt
cat input5.txt
#include <stdio.h>
...
```

However, when I press control + v to paste into gedit, it only pastes the actual last thing I copied within unity desktop, such as something from firefox browser.

How can I paste in gui applications something I copied from terminal?

Answer (score 107, accepted):

I think it is just a matter of understanding the different selection clipboards used by the `xclip` utility

```
   -selection
          specify  which X selection to use, options are "primary" to use
          XA_PRIMARY (default), "secondary" for  XA_SECONDARY  or  "clip‐
          board" for XA_CLIPBOARD
```

When you do `cat line-size.c | xclip` the default behaviour is to copy to the primary X selection buffer - to paste from that buffer, you need to use a mouse middle-click instead of the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> combination.

To copy into the clipboard instead, so that you can paste with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>, you would need to do

```
cat line-size.c | xclip -selection clipboard
```

Comment: It is equally as easy to paste by piping to xclip without additional arguments. Instead of Ctrl+v, just use middle mouse click.

Comment: That can be changed to `xclip < line-size.c -selection clipboard`

Comment: @SubhamoySengupta see my edit

Comment: The instruction `cat line-size.c | xclip -sel clip` has the same result that `cat line-size.c | xclip -selection clipboard`

Comment: I can't imagine the default use-case for `xclip` was to interact with something besides the user's clipboard.

Comment: What are the different selection(s) used for if not copy/paste? Ie. `options are "primary" to use XA_PRIMARY (default), "secondary" for  XA_SECONDARY  or  "clip‐board" for XA_CLIPBOARD`

Answer (score 14):

Just in case if someone is looking for a shortest version without using aliases.
By using `something|xclip -se c` instead of just bare `something|xclip` you can press **Ctrl+V/Ctrl+Shift+V** and see a desirable result. Where `something — cat somefile.txt` for example.